# Extract Values between two strings in a text file

Tags: python, file, csv

Lets say I have a Text file with the below content

```
fdsjhgjhg
fdshkjhk
 Start
     Good Morning
     Hello World
 End
dashjkhjk
dsfjkhk
Start
  hgjkkl
  dfghjjk
  fghjjj
Start
   Good Evening
   Good 
End
```

I wrote the following code:

```
infile = open('test.txt','r')
outfile= open('testt.txt','w')
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Start":
        copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "End":
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

I have this result in outfile:

```
     Good Morning
     Hello World
     hgjkkl
     dfghjjk
     fghjjj
     Good Evening
     Good
```

My problem is I want to take just the data between start and end but not between start and start or End and End

Comment: You should try to use a buffer variable to store what is encountered after "Start" until you meet "End" then write it to your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great problem! This is a bucket problem where each start needs an end.

The reason why you got the result is because there are two consecutive 'Start'.

It's best to *store* the information somewhere until 'End' is triggered.

```
infile = open('scores.txt','r')
outfile= open('testt.txt','w')
copy = False
for line in infile:

    if line.strip() == "Start":
        bucket = []
        copy = True

    elif line.strip() == "End":
        for strings in bucket:
            outfile.write( strings + '\n')
        copy = False

    elif copy:
        bucket.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a temporary list of lines, and only commit them after you know that a section meets your criteria. Maybe try something like the following:

```
infile = open('test.txt','r')
outfile= open('testt.txt','w')
copy = False
tmpLines = []
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Start":
        copy = True
        tmpLines = []
    elif line.strip() == "End":
        copy = False
        for tmpLine in tmpLines:
            outfile.write(tmpLine)
    elif copy:
        tmpLines.append(line)
```

This gives the output

```
     Good Morning
     Hello World
 Good Evening
 Good
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky but perhaps more intuitive way using regex. It finds all text that exists between "Start" and "End" pairs, and the print statement trims them off.

```
import re 
infile = open('test.txt','r')
text = infile.read() 

matches = re.findall('Start.*?End',text)
for m in matches: 
    print m.strip('Start ').strip(' End')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions.  This will exclude rogue `Start` and `End` lines.  Here is a [live example](https://regex101.com/r/vL7gF4)

```
import re

f = open('test.txt','r')
txt = f.read()
matches = re.findall(r'^\s*Start\s*$\n((?:^\s*(?!Start).*$\n)*?)^\s*End\s*$', txt, flags=re.M)
```

Comment: `Start\s*((?:(?!Start).*$\s)+?)\s*End` will be more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't expect to get nested structures, you could do this:

```
# match everything between "Start" and "End"
occurences = re.findall(r"Start(.*?)End", text, re.DOTALL)
# discard text before duplicated occurences of "Start"
occurences = [oc.rsplit("Start", 1)[-1] for oc in occurences]
# optionally trim whitespaces
occurences = [oc.strip("\n") for oc in occurences]
```

Which prints

```
>>> for oc in occurences: print(oc)
     Good Morning
     Hello World
   Good Evening
   Good
```

You can add the `\n` as part of `Start` and `End` if you want